# Android show user a feedback on screen when running background task

Tags: android, notifications, background-task

I want to show feedback to user when user is using my app and a background task is running. I don't want to show it on the notification area but just on the screen, for example under the user's name showing 'syncing ...'

Similar functionality is found in Wunderlist app when it is syncing I can see it shows 'syncing' under my username.

Please help me what I should do in order to achieve that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a handler in your UI thread, then have your background thread post Runnables to that handler with code to show Syncing....

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @scubasteve623 I've been able to implement Runnable to post message on UI thread.